# Is it right to put really specific methods in DAO classes?

Tags: java, dao

All of the examples I've read about DAO classes only show DAO classes with very general methods, for example, insertNewCar(), deleteCar(), updateCar(), getCars(), getCarByID(). But can I put more specific methods into a DAO class?
 In my case, I need to get all doctors who are having a shift today, and to know that, I have to get all doctors' scedules which have the date equal to today. Right now, I'm getting those doctors by a single method in doctorDAO class called getDoctorsWorkingToday(ArrayList scedulesToday). In this method, I first get all ids of doctors from the arraylist and attact them into a complete sql query. And the rest of the method is just like a normal "get" method: I use the query to get all doctors I want, put them into an arraylist and return it.
 It works fine, but is that solution acceptable? Or must I only use general methods in DAO class like getAllSchedules() and getAllDoctors(), and do all the filter stuff in other classes?

Comment: Seems acceptable to me, what is your definition of done?

Comment: The only bad thing i see in your approach is you may have a lot of  unneeded trips between the daos and the database. For instance finding the schedules apparently happens in one query. Then the result is returned and used in another query. You could have one query do all the work in one trip. So maybe what you have isnt specific enough.

Comment: Hi Nathan, I'm following a design pattern showed in my teacher's slide. In the pattern, each entity class has its own DAO class, so the Doctor class has a DoctorDAO class to access Doctor table in database. So I thought it'd be wrong if I joined Doctor table and Schedule table into another table and selected the adequate doctors from that table, because I wasn't getting doctors from Doctor table.

Comment: Yeah that is a screwy kind of pattern. Ok for class projects but will not be good in real life.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding , I usually put all db specific code (queries) in DAO's and transaction handling and business logic in service layer. This allows for service methods to invoke methods across multiple dao's and keep it all within same transaction. In my opinion, this is allows for better code reuse across dao's.

In your case, 
Use 'get' method business logic in Service layer and Query related stuff in dao.

It's upto you, how you are implementing the service and dao.  Just for the flow and easy understanding,we are following the standards.